# Setting unique id for each element in a dropdownlistfor (MVC)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, razor

I can't seem to figure out how to set a unique ID for each element in a `SelectList` (using `@Html.DropDownListFor`). The div in view looks like this currently:

```
<div id="Courses">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.Courses, new SelectList(Model.Courses, "CourseID", "Name"), "Choose Course", new { id = "courseDropDown", @class = "form-control input-sm", data_width = "100%" })
</div>
```

Inspecting the element in the browser shows that each element has the `courseID` as a value, what I would like is for each element to have this courseID as a unique id. FYI `Model.Courses` contains an enumerable of all my courses.

For the sake of completeness the reason I want this is that I have a highChart in a partial view which corresponds to the dropdownlist, and I have a button from my course page which redirects to the view with the partial div on it and loads the chart for a given course (using the ID from the coursepage). This works fine, but I just now need the `dropdownlist` to display the name of that course upon page load, whereas now it simply says *'Choose Phishing Campaign'*

Any help or advice is appreciated.

edit: Thanks for tidying the code up Rory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to set default value of `select` you should set some kind of `CourseId` property of model in your controller and then in your View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.CourseId, new SelectList(Model.Courses, "CourseID", "Name"), "Choose Course", new { id = "courseDropDown", @class = "form-control input-sm", data_width = "100%" })
```

`DropDownListFor` helper set this value selected on page load.

Comment: can you shouw your ViewModel and controller? Then i edit my question to show you how you can change them

Comment: I got this fixed, and forgot to update the thread. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Within the Model or controller, where you are populating the Course property you set the CourseId as a unique number.

Really it matters on the way your setting the property?

```
foreach(var course in DataSource.CourseTitles)
   viewModel.Courses.Add(new Course(){ CourseId = i++, Name = course})
```

Answer (score 1):

**teo van kot's**  answer is correct (+1).

Though if you dont need to bind the CourseId for a post. you could use the `SelectList` [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553(v=vs.118).aspx):-

```
public SelectList(
    IEnumerable items,
    string dataValueField,
    string dataTextField,
    Object selectedValue
)
```

like so:-

```
<div id="Courses">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.Courses, new SelectList(Model.Courses, "CourseID", "Name", "COURSEID"), "Choose Course", new { id = "courseDropDown", @class = "form-control input-sm", data_width = "100%" })
</div>
```

Comment: this looks promising, but after trying it and inspecting in the browser I can't see any sign of the 'COURSEID' part. What is this referencing? I feel I may have the name wrong.

Comment: you need to replace 'COURSEID' with the actual course id. which is the value of the option you want to set.